# osx - change terminal-color based on user

Tags: macos, bash, ssh, terminal, .bash-profile

what i want to achieve :

everytime i log onto a machine via ssh with a specific user -> "danger"
   like `ssh danger@somehost`

i want the terminal to change its background to red, so i have a visual feedback that im in a bash with a specific user and not terminal on my own machine.

I can only set the options manually and i dont have a clue, there must be
something i can write into bashprofile or so  ?!

for any hint, thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made it using [iTerm2](http://www.iterm2.com/) and some AppleScript. 
Here's the function for shells (bash or zsh) that changes the background color:

```
function iterm_bg_color() {
  local tty=$(tty)
  osascript -e "
    tell application \"iTerm\"
      repeat with theTerminal in terminals
        tell theTerminal
          try
            tell session id \"$tty\"
              set background color to {(($1 * 257)), (($2 * 257)), (($3 * 257))} as RGB color
            end tell
          on error errmesg number errn
          end try
        end tell
      end repeat
    end tell"
}
```

Use it like that to turn the background red:

```
$ iterm_bg_color 255 0 0
```

I also made some aliases to shortcut starting ssh as some user, just like that:

```
alias ssd="iterm_bg_color 30 0 0; ssh danger@somehost; iterm_bg_color 0 0 0"
```

Or you could write a wrapper that would colour the ssh based entirely on a user. Something like that, for `bash`:

```
function ssh() {
    if [[ $1 == danger@* ]]; then
        iterm_bg_color 50 0 0
        /usr/bin/ssh "$@"
        iterm_bg_color 0 0 0
    else
        /usr/bin/ssh "$@"
    fi
}
```

or for `zsh`:

```
function ssh() {
    if [[ "$1" =~ "danger@.*" ]]; then
        iterm_bg_color 50 0 0
        /usr/bin/ssh $*
        iterm_bg_color 0 0 0
    else
        /usr/bin/ssh $*
    fi
}
```

Just place the `iterm_bg_color` in your shell config (`~/.bash_profile` or `~/.zshrc` respectively) and add the `ssh()` function (or alias) to make it automatically colored when you connect.

Comment: nicecreme, that looks pretty cool! I will give it a try and i hope installing iterm, won´t kill all my previous configuration, i´m not too sure about ^^ thanks lot

Comment: So i gave it a try and im not fully understanding what zsh is, i had it installed before ( i think ), so when i type "zsh" the "$" in terminal changes to "%" but i cant connect with ssh while in zsh mode, and i dont find the .zshrc file

Comment: `zsh` is an alternative shell for your default one, which is called `bash`. I updated the answer that has function for the `.bashrc`. Create a `~/.bashrc` file (if it doesn't exist yet), and paste these functions (`iterm_bg_color` and `ssh` for the bash shell) there.

Comment: YEAh it works perfect !  thank you very very much  !

Comment: note : it worked when i putted it into ~/.bash_profile

Comment: @johnSmith Oops, sorry :)